# K8S: How do I delete deployments with 0 replicas

Tags: kubernetes

How do I clear old deployments? I'm able shrink a deployment to 0 replicas via `kubectl scale deployment.v1.apps/hello-kubernetes3 --replicas=0`, but as shown below they're still present in some form.

```
$ kubectl get rs -o wide
NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS         IMAGES                            SELECTOR
hello-kubernetes-5cb547b7d     1         1         1       27m   hello-kubernetes   paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8   app=hello-kubernetes,pod-template-hash=5cb547b7d
hello-kubernetes-6d9fd679cd    0         0         0       32m   hello-kubernetes   paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8   app=hello-kubernetes,pod-template-hash=6d9fd679cd
hello-kubernetes3-6d9fd679cd   0         0         0       25m   hello-kubernetes   paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.8   app=hello-kubernetes,pod-template-hash=6d9fd679cd
```

Comment: because what you are doing is not deleting the deployment but setting the desired replica count to 0. you deployment now watches, that you have always have a pod count of 0 for your deployment. 

try "kubectl delete ${insert your deployment here}. This will delete your deployment, associated replicasets and pods of this deployment (if they have not been scaled to 0)

Comment: So in the end I was able to do kubectl delete deployment hello-kubernetes, but in the above case how would I get rid of hello-kubernetes-6d9fd679cd without removing hello-kubernetes-5cb547b7d? Not sure how I got that particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer as a part of it would be based on @meaningqo comment but I would like to share some more light on this topic with a help of the official documentations.

What you were doing in the first place is not deleting a deployment but actually scaling it to 0. In order to delete a deployment or any other resource you should use the [kubectl delete command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete):

> Delete resources by filenames, stdin, resources and names, or by
> resources and label selector.
>
> JSON and YAML formats are accepted. Only one type of the arguments may
> be specified: filenames, resources and names, or resources and label
> selector.

Note that:

> Some resources, such as pods, support graceful deletion. These
> resources define a default period before they are forcibly terminated
> (the grace period) (...) Because these resources often represent
> entities in the cluster, deletion may not be acknowledged immediately.

So you may want to wait a bit before seeing the results.

Referring to your second question. There are also other options aimed to work with `ReplicaSets` specifically:

- [Deleting a ReplicaSet and its Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#deleting-a-replicaset-and-its-pods)
- [Deleting just a ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#deleting-just-a-replicaset)

I also recommend familiarizing yourself with the whole [ReplicaSet guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) for better understanding of this particular topic.

Answer (score 0):

From kubernetes terminology you can delete any component with below pattern

`kubectl delete <component type> <name> <-n namespace>`

Example: kubectl delete deployment hello-world -n mynamespace

Most commonly used component types are pod, deployment, replicaset, statefulset, services and so on.